# Meteor use prerender with Ngix

Tags: meteor, nginx, prerender

I use prerender-node with my Meteor APP, and when i test the crawl on local, i've 302 status code with `localhost:3000/http://stephane-richin.fr` :

```
2016-09-20T07:43:13.953Z got 302 in 329ms for http://stephane-richin.fr/
```

If i test with 'www' : `localhost:3000/http://www.stephane-richin.fr`, the status code is 200 (so correct) :

```
2016-09-20T07:46:59.685Z got 200 in 1570ms for http://www.stephane-richin.fr/
```

So i think my Ngix config is not good :

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           www.stephane-richin.fr;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/app.dev.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/app.dev.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }

  location @prerender {
    proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token xxxxxxxxxxx;

    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link previ$
      set $prerender 1;
    }

    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
      set $prerender 1;
    }

    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
      set $prerender 0;
    }

    if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif$
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    if ($prerender = 1) {
      set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
      rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
      proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }

    if ($prerender = 0) {
      rewrite .* /index.html break;
    }
  }
}

server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           stephane-richin.fr;

  location / {

    if ($http_host ~ "^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$"){
      rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.stephane-richin.fr/$1 redirect;
    }

  }
}
```

Anyone can help me about my config Nginx ? I think the problem is this.

Thank you !

Comment: Looks like you have it set up correctly then. Does http://www.stephane-richin.fr?_escaped_fragment_= show a prerendered page with a status code 200?

Comment: Nop. But www.stephane-richin.fr have status code 200 !